# Memory management: retain cycle with weak var, non retain cycle with unowned. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, retain-cycle

TL;DR

I have a struct and a class. The struct has a reference to an instance of the class, and the object has a closure that captures the struct.
If the reference to the object is **unowned** it seems that both of them get deinitialised. If the reference to the object is **weak** they retain each other. 
**Why?**

I have a struct and a class that may reference to each other and I was trying to figure out retain cycles and ways to break them. So I played a little bit with playground.

Given this code:

```
    struct A {
    unowned var b: B

    init(b: B) {
        self.b = b
    }

    func setup() {
        print("A setup")

        b.didSomethingClosure = {
            print("A: b did do something")
            self.printSomething()
        }
    }

    func printSomething() {
        print("A: A did do something")
    }
}

class B {

    var didSomethingClosure:(() -> Void)?

    func doSomething() {
        print("B: do something")
        didDoSomething()
    }

    func didDoSomething() {
        print("B: did something")
        if let closure = didSomethingClosure {
            closure()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("B: deinit")
    }
}


do {

    let b = B()
    let a = A(b: b)

    a.setup()
    b.doSomething()

    print("end do")
}
```

If var b in the struct is declared as `unowned var b: B`, the B object is released. If I modify the code to `weak var b: B?` and then `b?.didSomethingClosure = ...`, the B object is retained. Why?

Comment: unowned var? That wouldn't even compile...

Comment: Why wouldn't it compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose problem is that you run it in `Playground`. Try to run it in real app and you will see that `B` is deallocated

```
struct A {
    weak var b: B?

    init(b: B) {
        self.b = b
    }

    func setup() {
        print("A setup")

        b?.didSomethingClosure = {
            print("A: b did do something")
            self.printSomething()
        }
    }

    func printSomething() {
        print("A: A did do something")
    }
}

class B {

    var didSomethingClosure:(() -> Void)?

    func doSomething() {
        print("B: do something")
        didDoSomething()
    }

    func didDoSomething() {
        print("B: did something")
        if let closure = didSomethingClosure {
            closure()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("B: deinit")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let b = B()
        let a = A(b: b)

        a.setup()
        b.doSomething()

        print("end do") // B is deallocated here
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoaa. It didn't cross my mind. It didn't make any sense either. Is there an explanation or is it just a bug?

Comment: @bursyllac it seems like a playground bug. I played with you code a little and this issue is not related to closures and memory management at all